# How to generate device specific unique ids with javascript at the client side?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way to generate a device specific unique identifier at the client side.
i tried fingerprintjs, it works well but the identifier generated will change when i use a different browser. Is there any other way i can generate a system specific string which is constant across any browser?

Thanks In Advance!

This is something i tried with fingerprintjs. It Kind of works but it gives different strings when different browsers are used.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://openfpcdn.io/fingerprintjs/v3/iife.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
const fpPromise = FingerprintJS.load();

fpPromise
  .then(fp => fp.get())
  .then(result => {
    const deviceId = result.visitorId;
    console.log('Device ID:', deviceId);
    document.getElementById('text').innerText=deviceId;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });

</script>
</head>
<body style="display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items:center;">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h2>Your Devices Unique ID is</h2>
    <h1 id="text" style="font-size: 5em;"></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So IP address + fingerprint sort on IP address.